# How can I generate n random values from a bimodal distribution in Python?

Tags: python, random, normal-distribution

I tried generating and combining two unimodal distributions but think there's something wrong in my code.

```
N=400
mu, sigma = 100, 5
mu2, sigma2 = 10, 40
X1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, N)
X2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, N)
w = np.random.normal(0.5, 1, N)
X = w*X1 + (1-w)*X2
X = X.reshape(-1,2)
```

When I plot X I don't get a bimodal distribution

Comment: If `w` are supposed to be weights, you'll get weights below zero and above one; that may not be what you intend.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's unclear where your problem is; it's also unclear what the purpose of the variable `w` is, and it's unclear how you judge you get an incorrect result, since we don't see the plot code, or any other code to confirm or reject a binomial distribution.
That is, your example is too incomplete to *exactly* answer your question. But I can make an educated guess.

If I do the following below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=400
mu, sigma = 100, 5
mu2, sigma2 = 10, 40
X1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, N)
X2 = np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, N)
X = np.concatenate([X1, X2])
plt.hist(X)
```

and that yields the following figure:

[image: histogram of X]

Comment: Thank you. What I was trying to do with w was randomly assign either x1 or x2 to X so the X total was 400.

Comment: @ejwmv In that case, you should use a random distribution with just two values (0 and 1 in your case), not another random distribution. But it may be easier to split N beforehand randomly, with a total of 400. E.g., (random) 166 for X1 and 234 for X2. That should yield the same result.